# Is jq internal sort slower than GNU sort?

Tags: sort, jq, coreutils, benchmark, optimization

While filtering through [this json file](https://iptv-org.github.io/iptv/channels.json) I did a [benchmark](https://github.com/sharkdp/hyperfine) and found out utilizing jq's internal `sort` and `unique` method is actually **25% slower** than `sort --unique`!

| Command | Mean [ms] | Min [ms] | Max [ms] | Relative |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `jq "[.[].category] \| sort \| unique" channels.json` | 172.0 ± 2.6 | 167.8 | 176.8 | 1.25 ± 0.06 |
| `jq "[.[].category \| select((. != null) and (. != \"XXX\"))] \| sort \| unique" channels.json` | 151.9 ± 4.1 | 146.5 | 163.9 | 1.11 ± 0.06 |
| `jq ".[].category" channels.json \| sort -u` | 137.2 ± 6.6 | 131.8 | 156.6 | 1.00 |

```
Summary
  'jq ".[].category" channels.json | sort -u' ran
    1.11 ± 0.06 times faster than 'jq "[.[].category | select((. != null) and (. != \"XXX\"))] | sort | unique" channels.json'
    1.25 ± 0.06 times faster than 'jq "[.[].category] | sort | unique" channels.json'
```

test command:

```bsh
hyperfine --warmup 3 \
    'jq "[.[].category] | sort | unique" channels.json'  \
    'jq "[.[].category | select((. != null) and (. != \"XXX\"))] | sort | unique" channels.json' \
    'jq ".[].category" channels.json | sort -u'
```

If we only test sort (without uniqueness), again jq is **9% slower** than sort:

| Command | Mean [ms] | Min [ms] | Max [ms] | Relative |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `jq "[.[].category] \| sort" channels.json` | 133.9 ± 1.6 | 131.1 | 138.2 | 1.09 ± 0.02 |
| `jq ".[].category" channels.json \| sort` | 123.0 ± 1.3 | 120.5 | 125.7 | 1.00 |

```
Summary
  'jq ".[].category" channels.json | sort' ran
    1.09 ± 0.02 times faster than 'jq "[.[].category] | sort" channels.json'
```

versions:

```
jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe
sort (GNU coreutils) 8.28
```

I expected using jq's internal functions would result in a faster processing than piping into an external app which itself should be spawned. Am I using jq poorly?

**update**
Just repeated this experiment on host with FLASH storage, Arm CPU and these versions:

```
jq-1.6
sort (GNU coreutils) 8.32
```

result:

```
Benchmark #1: jq "[.[].category] | sort" channels.json
  Time (mean ± σ):     587.8 ms ±   3.9 ms    [User: 539.5 ms, System: 44.2 ms]
  Range (min … max):   582.8 ms … 594.2 ms    10 runs
 
Benchmark #2: jq ".[].category" channels.json | sort
  Time (mean ± σ):     606.0 ms ±   8.6 ms    [User: 569.5 ms, System: 49.0 ms]
  Range (min … max):   589.6 ms … 616.2 ms    10 runs
 
Summary
  'jq "[.[].category] | sort" channels.json' ran
    1.03 ± 0.02 times faster than 'jq ".[].category" channels.json | sort'
```

Now jq sort runs 3% faster than GNU sort :D

Comment: `jq` uses your C library's `qsort()` implementation. All your tests are running in sub-second time, indicating that any memory admin overhead is likely significantly affecting the results, so we can't say more than possibly "okay". Test again on data that takes around 2 to 5 seconds to sort. Spawning a single process to run `sort` is quick (it's not as if you're running a shell loop, spawning `sort` in every iteration or something).

Comment: jq's sort operation is not specialised to strings, so it is also fundamentally doing more work with every comparison.

Comment: I re-did your benchmarks with much more data, and I can only say that I confirmed your numbers. The difference in timing is probably due to using different sorting algorithms. Running the `sort` utility with `--debug` on my OpenBSD system indicates that it's using Radix Sort.

Comment: @Kusalananda Good to know. Latest version of jq? So my problem has boiled down to whether I want to add a `sort` dependency or tolerate a ~20% speed penalty

Comment: @Zeta.Investigator Well, the _real_ question is whether you tolerate that your code runs for 20 to 50 milliseconds longer.  I would say that it probably doesn't matter too much (not knowing anything about your project, obviously).  Also, you shouldn't need to add a dependency on `sort` as that is a standard Unix utility and I'd be _really_ surprised if that was not available on any Unix system that you'll come across.

Comment: @Zeta.Investigator  That depends whether the penalty is 20% of five seconds, or 20% of two hours, and also whether it runs once an hour or once a month.

Comment: Just to say that the OpenBSD `sort` allows for specifying `--qsort`. Running `sort --qsort | uniq` (`-u` can't be used with `--qsort`), I get _exactly_ the same identical timings as with `sort | unique` in `jq`.

Comment: @Kusalananda I've updated my post. On another system, jq runs 3% faster